# Invalid URL provided Zone angular error while on IIS production Server

Tags: angular, iis

We have Angular app which is functioning properly on the local environment and after moving to the production one we have some wired error and we can not identify what is exactly causing this error.

we make a production build using `ng build --prod`
then we move the `dist` folder to the server
then on the production server we made a site on `IIS` which refer to this dist folder `using self signed SSL certificate` and bound to the server domain

but we still receiving the following error
[image]

Comment: have you changed the base href?

Comment: yes we changed it to the new domain name

Comment: so you do `ng build --prod --base-href <url here>`?

Comment: yes, and we still have the same error

Comment: one thing to note, angular doesnt really like self signed certs, unless you do a manual install on each browser that will be using the webpage